# Is there a way to not download body during Java HttpClient call when the resource is large?

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, apache-commons

I'm trying to prevent org.apache.http.client.HttpClient ([link text](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html)) from downloading the body when the resource let's say over 10 MB.

What I have done after searching here, and others is do a HEAD call, then check the Content-Length header, and if it's < 10MB, do a GET call, finally do something with the response body.

Would there be a better solution to this? I want to avoid an extra call.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do a regular call and check the length, and if the length > 10MB then just break and cancel the download. But the problem is that socket will still download as much as possible before you cancel. I think doing a HEAD call is the best method.

Answer (score 2):

The Best way is definitely to do the HTTP HEAD since HEAD request for **only** header information on file or resource (as stipulated on [RFC1945](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt), Section 8.2).

From the response of the HEAD call, retrieve the `Content-Length` message header and see if the size is less than or greater than 10MB.

Doing a GET will result in returning the full entity body.

Apache [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/head.html) (Version 3) supports HTTP HEAD.